# Python TinyDB Get last record in db

Tags: python, tinydb

I am trying to get the last record from my tinyDB, so I want to make a query that looks like that:
`"SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1"`
which should give me the last row. though I can't figure out how to do it with TinyDB.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to order db by time descending for example:

```
od = sorted(db.all(), key=lambda k: k['time'])
print(od[-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, the following would return the doc id of the final element in the db in TinyDB 4.7.0:

```
el = db.all()[-1]
record = db.get(doc_id=el.doc_id)
```

[Using Document IDs](https://tinydb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#using-document-ids)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
table = db.table('table_name')
table.get(doc_id=len(table))
```

See the way of `doc_id` [here](https://tinydb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#using-document-ids)

Comment: You should not compare doc_id value and len(table) if you made some remove removed.
If you have

    `{"1":{...}, "2":{...}, "3":{...}}`

if you do :

    `t.remove(doc_ids=[2])`

you obtains:
      `{"1":{...}, "3":{...}}`

Answer (score 0):

Using a `Query` and doing an update :

```
with TinyDB('db.json') as db:
    my_table = db.table('a_table_name')
    my_query= Query()
    first_of_table_for_this_query = my_table.search(my_query.some_field == some_value)[1]
    last_of_table_for_this_query = my_table.search(my_query.some_field == some_value)[-1]
    # exemple of use for updating first inserted and last inserted only
    my_table.update({'some_field': some_value+42}, doc_ids=[
        first_of_table_for_this_query,
        last_of_table_for_this_query
    ])
```